# How can I reduce the size of a 5 layer for-loop

Tags: python, optimization, refactoring

I've developed a code to translate an RNA sequence into a peptide, and I need to reduce its level of indentation to reduce the space and improve readability

The biological concept of translation basically consists in reading a sequence of letters (usually RNA), 3 by 3, and for each of those triplets, assign an amino acid according to a table.

The process of getting a sequence and split it in triplets is well done and  refactored,

```
seq_codons = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range((-1 + frame), len(sequence), 3)]
```

but the rest is just a giant dictionary and a ridiculous 5-layer for-loop that works, but it is far from optimized.

Here is the full code:

```
sequence = 'ACUGAUCUGAGACGUCAUCGUAGCAUCGU'


def translation(sequence, frame=1):  # Here, the frame just means from where starts
    codons_table = {                 # to count the triplets: A, C or U, in the exemple
        "CYS": ("UGU", "UGC",),
        "GLN": ("CAA", "CAG",),
        "GLU": ("GAA", "GAG",),
        "GLY": ("GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG",),
        "HIS": ("CAU", "CAC",),
        "ILE": ("AUU", "AUC", "AUA",),
        "LEU": ("UUA", "UUG", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG",),
        "LYS": ("AAA", "AAG",),
        "MET": ("AUG",),
        "PHE": ("UUU", "UUC",),
        "PRO": ("CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG",),
        "SER": ("UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG", "AGU", "AGC",),
        "THR": ("ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG",),
        "TRP": ("UGG",),
        "TYR": ("UAU", "UAC",),
        "VAL": ("GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG",),
        "STOP": ("UAG", "UGA", "UAA",),
        "ASP": ("GAU", "GAC",),
        "ASN": ("AAU", "AAC",),
        "ARG": ("CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGA", "AGG",),
        "ALA": ("GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG",)
    }
    seq_codons = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range((-1 + frame), len(sequence), 3)]
    print(seq_codons)
    peptide = []

    for codon in seq_codons:
        for amino_acid, table_codon in zip(codons_table, codons_table.values()):
            if len(table_codon) > 1:
                for single_codon in table_codon:
                    if single_codon == codon:
                        peptide.append(amino_acid)
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                if table_codon[0] == codon:
                    peptide.append(amino_acid)
                else:
                    pass

    return peptide

print(translation(sequence))
```

I wonder if there is a way to reduce the size of the last for-loop, and if there is a better way to store the data, other then using a dictionary

Comment: Take a look at `itertools`, there's probably some functions there that will fit your need.

Comment: @Barmar I'll look for it, thanks. Any clue as to which function may be appropriated?

Comment: Probably `combinations`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to remap the `codons_table` in this way, so you can have direct access (print `codons_map` to see what I mean):

```
codons_map = {}
for k, v in codons_table.items():
  for item in v:
    codons_map[item] = k
```

Then, as you did split the string by three:

```
sequence = 'ACUGAUCUGAGACGUCAUCGUAGCAUCGU'
seq_codons = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3)]
```

Finally iterate over the `seq_codons`:

```
peptide = []
for item in seq_codons:
  if len(item) == 3:
    peptide.append(codons_map[item])

print(peptide)
#=> ['THR', 'ASP', 'LEU', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'HIS', 'ARG', 'SER', 'ILE']
```

---

**Short way**

```
codons_map = { item: k for k, v in codons_table.items() for item in v }
seq_codons = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3)]
peptide = [ codons_map[item] for item in seq_codons if len(item) == 3 ]

print(peptide)

#=> ['THR', 'ASP', 'LEU', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'HIS', 'ARG', 'SER', 'ILE']
```

Comment: :-)  You finished the same solution while I was in a meeting!
Deleted my post; good work.

Comment: that was just perfect.